# Fetch post contents from WordPress from a specific category and display on a webpage

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I m trying to fetch WordPress POST data - title, description, date and image from WordPress and display the contents on a different webpage.

```
var URL = 'url';
  $.getJSON({
    url: URL,
    type: "get",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(data) {
        $('.blog').text('No Blogs Found!');
    }
  });
});
```

I'm able to get the error but it does not the success part.

I'm using jQuery and Ajax to trying to fetch the data from WordPress.

Comment: Since `$.getJSON` and `$.ajax` should be pretty much equivalent, your url should be fetching `admin-ajax.php`. And for that you'd need to [localize script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script), and set the url like: `wp_localize_script('your_handle', 'localize_function_name', array('ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin_ajax.php')));`. Then your url is `url: localize_function_name.ajaxurl,`

Comment: I am not sure how to implement this @dingo_d

Comment: Well in your `functions.php` just add that localize script and add the handle (usually existing handle that will have jquery as a dependency), add your own function name, and in your jquery code add the url as I've said in the post. Check these posts about AJAX in wordpress: [post 1](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins), [post 2](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)) and [post 3](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX)

Comment: What do you mean by "different webpage"?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the feed data of a WordPress site like this from outside:
http://examplewpsite.com/feed/?category=yourcategory

With simplexml_load_file($feedurl) you can put the desired data in an array like this:

```
$feed = simplexml_load_file($feedurl);
$feed_array = array();
foreach($feed->channel->item as $story){
    $story_array = array (
        'title' => $story->title,
        'desc' => $story->description,
        'link' => $story->link,
        'date' => $story->date
    );
    array_push($feed_array, $story_array);
}
```